# How to store meta field values

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I would like to store a few extra details for my custom post type, using meta boxes. Should I store all the values under one meta key in an array, or create several meta key and value pairs?

Comment: Please define your "few extra details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the values to sort or filter the data, you should keep them as separate entries.

Comment: and if not, I should use an array? Does it improve performance or have any other benefit?

Comment: I don't know if it improves performance or not.

Comment: meta data are intended to be discrete key => value pairs. You should store them as such. You gain no performance improvements by trying to force them into an array.